# django delete object using AJAX or javascript with confirm

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, request

hello I want to delete a Django object using AJAX or JavaScript  with confirm message on clicking delete but I don't know how to complete AJAX request.

views.py

```
def delete(request,id):
    try:
        inta = work.objects.get(pk=id)
        inta.delete()
    except:
        pass
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.delete, name='delete')
```

html :

```
{& for app in apps &}
<p>{{ app.item0 }}</p>
<p>{{ app.item1 }}</p>
<p>{{ app.item2 }}</p>
<button  data-object-id="{{ app.id }}">remove</button>
{% endfor %}

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var confirmation = confirm("are you sure you want to remove the item?");
    if (confirmation) {
     // execute ajax
        alert('removed');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There is more convinient way to write AJAX code:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let confirmation = confirm("are you sure you want to remove the item?");
    if (confirmation) {
        let object_id = $(this).attr('data-object-id');
        let url = `delete/${object_id}/`;
        $.ajax({
           url: "example.html/my/example",
           data: {
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
           },
           type: "DELETE",
           dataType: "json"
         }).done(
              function(){alert("Deleted");}
            ).fail(
              function(){alert("Error");}
            ) 
       });
    }
})
```

Comment: I get this error Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):

Comment: I forgot about csrf token in data. Now it should work ;)

Comment: I change some lines in your code and now  if I try to delete some itam then I take fail (alert error) but the item delete it and I can see that only if I refresh the page here the snippet:
        var object_id = $(this).attr('data-object-id');
        console.log(object_id);
        //var url = 'delete/${object_id}/';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'delete/'+object_id+'/',
            data: {
            },
              beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- The `delete` view excepts a DELETE request
- The javascript code is contained in the HTML

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let confirmation = confirm("are you sure you want to remove the item?");
    if (confirmation) {
        let object_id = $(this).attr('data-object-id');
        let url = `delete/${object_id}/`;
        $.delete(url, {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}, function(){
                alert('removed');
        })
    }
})
```

If the javascript code is in a separate file you will have to find another way to get the `csrf-token`, perhaps from a hidden input somewhere on the page.

Comment: but I need first  to agree  to confirm message  before delete object some like this ` var confirmation = confirm("are you sure you want to remove the item?"); ` I am confused now

Comment: The code you posted already handles the confirmation... Anyway I updated the answer to make it clearer

Comment: I try to test it now but don't work if I put code in <script></script> then show me error in ` let` I thing because have red line.

Comment: @Mar You are probably using an older version of JS. Try to replace all `let` with `var`

Comment: I take now error : (index):679 Uncaught TypeError: $.delete is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):679)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)